# 60 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I get 2 errors as seen in the image.

I'm not able to run my project and continuously either get an issue where firebase pod is not found or these 2 errors seen in the image. **How do I resolve this?**

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give an example of the "symbols" in question and then "Find in Project" and screenshot the result. 
It's hard to say where the problem comes from with just what you gave us here. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try going to

```
Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data
```

Quit Xcode, then delete the derived data folder, then go to your project in folder in `Finder`, delete the `Podfile.lock` file and `Pod` folder

Then , do a fresh `pod install` and open your project workspace and compile and run.